# What are examples of AI that use philosophy derived ontologies?

Tags: classification, philosophy, logic, ontology

I'm looking for AI systems or natural language processors that use, in the classification and interrelation of notions/objects, some philosophical system, like basic laws of logic, Kantian or empiricism.

I have also read about goal-seeking procedures. Are these based on psychology fields and some particular psychology theory or these are ad hoc experiments, with only general terms applied?

Answer (score 1):

Excellent question!  I'm currently working on the pre-Socratics as the most basic philosophies for first principles (These philosophers are intriguing for their simplicity and universality, and the "dawn of consciousness", in some conceptions, may be ascribed to the Classical Era.  Linguistically, ancient Greek is fundamental to meaning in the West.)

However, I was pointed at this very interesting blog post "[Algorithms of the Mind](https://arimo.com/featured/2015/algorithms-of-the-mind/)" which has some useful links, and discusses Kant, which you may find useful.